# Is it OK to add a localhost exception to RedirectToLocal when Url.IsLocalUrl() is being called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

VS2103, MVC5, VB

When running on the Localhost while developing, Url.IsLocalUrl() returns a false.

**Added for Chris:**  When a user does something on a page such as selecting items to purchase without logging in first, they will eventually have to log in to continue.  When the log in page is accessed from whatever page they are on, after log in we would want to send the user back to the page from which log in was accessed.  So a returnUrl is added as a parameter to be sent to the Login Function so it knows where to return to after log in.  But on successful log in, the Login Function executes a RedirectToLocal(returnUrl) method as shown below.  It's a protection.  But in the localhost environment, the built-in Url.IsLocalUrl() doesn't seem to like localhost Url's, so I added the clause as noted below to effectively 'override' the Url.IsLocalUrl() false return.  (Sorry I was too brief before)

I added the 'Or' clause to the If statment as below.  If the returnUrl includes the substring 'localhost:', then the second condition goes true and the redirect will occur, which it didn't do before in the development environment.

```
Public Function RedirectToLocal(returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
  If Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) Or (InStr(returnUrl, "localhost:") > 0) Then
    Return Redirect(returnUrl)
  End If
  Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
End Function
```

Is this a bad idea for any reason, or is there an easier way to get the desired behavior in the development environment?

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Alan

Comment: I _believe_ `IsLocalUrl` is checking to see if any domain name has been included. Anything _local_ to the site will either begin with `/path` or `relative/path` (and not `http:` or `https:` (or another protocol)).

Comment: Okay. I've read the question 5 times and I still can't make heads or tails out of what your asking. Perhaps my morning caffeine hasn't fully kicked in yet, but please try revising your question to make it more clear what you're trying to achieve and what problems you're experiencing.

Comment: @BradChristie: That is correct. `IsLocalUrl` was added to prevent open-redirection attacks. All it does is ensure that the value doesn't have a protocol and domain portion to the URL, so that in the situation of something like a `returnUrl` parameter passed in a querystring, the only thing that can ever be redirected to is some path on the same site.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I've sat on this for a while to make sure I understood the comments above and their implications.  Please confirm, what I wrote above is not defeating any protections regarding open-redirection attacks.  Since I'm only looking for 'localhost', that wouldn't be a threat on the production site, yes?